# How to get the meta information for a event attached to AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, xmlhttprequest

I want to ajax upload a file to the server and update the progress bar peroidically.
In the javascript, I have:

```
xhr.open('POST',' /path/to/upload', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-id", md5(filename+file.size));
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', onprogressHandler, false);
xhr.send(file);
```

In the event handler, I have :

```
function onprogressHandler(event) {
    var percent = event.loaded/event.total*100;
    var $target = $(event.target);
    console.log('ok');
    console.log($target);
    console.log('Upload progress: ' + percent + '%');
}
```

How can I get the information of the xhr request this event is attached to, like which file am I sending so that I can update the progress bar corresponding to that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that javascript has closures.

```
xhr.open('POST',' /path/to/upload', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name); //  you have file.name here
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-id", md5(filename+file.size));

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt) {
    console.log(file.name); // so its available here because of closures
    var percent = evt.loaded/evt.total*100;
    var $target = $(evt.target);
    console.log('ok');
    console.log($target);
    console.log('Upload progress: ' + percent + '%');
}

xhr.send(file);
```

In that simple example, because you use `file.name` in the `onprogress` callback, javascript knows to take the value with the callback and makes it available.